# Is it possible to uniquely solve $\mathbf{A}\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ for $\mathbf{A}$ (given $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{x}$)?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\mathbf{A}$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, $\vec{x}$ is an $n$-element vector, and $\vec{b}$ is an $n$ element vector, can the equation
$$\mathbf{A}\vec{x}=\vec{b}$$
be solved for $\mathbf{A}$ if I know $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{b}$? I have doubts because vectors (other than $1\times 1$) aren't invertible.

EDIT: x is not the zero vector and I actually want to obtain $A^{-1}$

Comment: Unless $x=0$ then yes (never uniquely). If $x=0$ and $b\neq0$ then no.

Comment: If $x$ is not the zero vector, you should be able to find an $A$ which works, but in general it is far from unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely **not uniquely**, consider
$$x = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1 \end{bmatrix}\hspace{10px}\text{ and }\hspace{10px} b = \begin{bmatrix}4\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
Then it holds for both
$$\mathbf{A}_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1&3\\2&-2\end{bmatrix}\hspace{10px}\text{ and }\hspace{10px} \mathbf{A}_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 3\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$
That
$$\mathbf{A}_1x=b \hspace{10px}\text{ and }\hspace{10px} \mathbf{A}_2x=b$$
and (infinitely many more), and both matrices are invertible.

Answer (score 1):

You may view your problem as follows: Write $A$ row-wise is a long vector, i.e.
$$a = \begin{bmatrix}a_{11}\\ \vdots \\ a_{1n}\\ a_{21}\\ \vdots \\ a_{2n}\\ \vdots \\ a_{m1}\\ \vdots \\a_{mn}\end{bmatrix}.$$
Now define a matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times {mn}}$ (assuming $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}^m$)  in block fashion
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix}
x^T & 0 & \dots & \\
0    & x^T & 0 & \\
     &     & \dots & \\
     &     &  & x^T
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
and your problem is in familiar notation: Solve
$$Xa = b$$
for $a$.

Comment: I'm a little but confused: The elements of a matrix are scalars, but you use x^T (a vector) as elements in X.