# "Dividing" matrix by a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

If I have $\mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{c}$ where $\mathbf{x} = 
\left[\begin{array}{r}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4\\
x_5
\end{array}\right]$ and $\mathbf{c} = \left[\begin{array}{r}
2x_1-4x_2-x_3-3x_4+2x_5\\
-x_1+2x_2+x_3+x_5\\
x_1-2x_2-x_3-3x_4-x_5\\
-x_1+4x_2-x_3+5x_5
\end{array}\right]$.
To solve the equation for $\mathbf{A}$, I would therefore like to isolate $\mathbf{A}$ - is there a way to do this? Like "dividing" by $\mathbf{a}$. I know that $\mathbf{A}$ is obviously the coefficient matrix but I would like some justification to actually show this like by mathematically solving the equation for $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768667/is-it-possible-to-uniquely-solve-mathbfa-vecx-vecb-for-mathbfa-g/768680#768680

Comment: One solution for $x\ne0$ takes the $i$th row of $A$ to be $(b_i/x^2)x^T$.

Comment: Arriving at $A$ as the result of some algorithm doesn't make it any more correct than an intuitive one.  I think the point of a question like this is to see if you get the concept of matrix-vector multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$Ax = A \cdot x =\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & a_{15}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & a_{25}\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
a_{41} & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & a_{45}
\end{array}\right]\cdot\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}\\
x_{3}\\
x_{4}\\
x_{5}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
a_{11} x_{1}+a_{12}x_{2}+a_{13}x_{3} +a_{14}x_{4} +a_{15}x_{5}\\
a_{21}x_{1}+a_{22}x_{2}+a_{23}x_{3}+a_{24}x_{4}+a_{25}x_{5}\\
a_{31}x_{1}+a_{32}x_{2}+a_{33}x_{3}+a_{34}x_{4}+a_{35}x_{5}\\
a_{41}x_{1}+a_{42}x_{2}+a_{43}x_{3}+a_{44}x_{4}+a_{45}x_{5}
\end{array}\right]$$

$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
a_{11} x_{1}+a_{12}x_{2}+a_{13}x_{3} +a_{14}x_{4} +a_{15}x_{5}\\
a_{21}x_{1}+a_{22}x_{2}+a_{23}x_{3}+a_{24}x_{4}+a_{25}x_{5}\\
a_{31}x_{1}+a_{32}x_{2}+a_{33}x_{3}+a_{34}x_{4}+a_{35}x_{5}\\
a_{41}x_{1}+a_{42}x_{2}+a_{43}x_{3}+a_{44}x_{4}+a_{45}x_{5}
\end{array}\right] =  \left[\begin{array}{r}
2x_1-4x_2-x_3-3x_4+2x_5\\
-x_1+2x_2+x_3+x_5\\
x_1-2x_2-x_3-3x_4-x_5\\
-x_1+4x_2-x_3+5x_5
\end{array}\right]$ $$

And you can continue from here.

Comment: But still, how did you get to $mathbf{A}$? Is it just guess-work that leads you to $\mathbf{A}$ from the beginning? Because you do not actually solve the equation by isolating $mathbf{A}$

Comment: well, it's pretty obvious. if $a_{11}x_{1} = 2x_1$ then $a_{11} = 2$ and so on

Comment: this is the meaning of a linear system equation, where the difference between the equations and the matrix is the multiplication by a vector of variables.

Comment: Once you understand this solution, you will see that the first line of your question is, in fact, a way of specifying the matrix $A$.  The coefficients you see inside of $c$ are the entries of the matrix $A$.

Answer (score -1):

Write the coefficient of $x_j$ in $i^{th}$ row of $x$ as elements $a_{ij}$ in **c**.

$\mathbf{c} = \left[\begin{array}{r}
2x_1-4x_2-x_3-3x_4+2x_5\\
-x_1+2x_2+x_3+x_5\\
x_1-2x_2-x_3-3x_4-x_5\\
-x_1+4x_2-x_3+5x_5
\end{array}\right]$

$\mathbf{A} = \left[\begin{matrix}
2& -4& -1& -3& 2\\
-1& 2& 1& 0& 1\\
1& -2& -1& -3& -1\\
-1& 4& -1& 0& 5
\end{matrix}\right]$

Comment: @Jneven $A_{4\times 5} x_{5\times 1}=c_{4\times 1}$